# I can change the setting options in dconf-editor, but the changes I make don't take effect.

Tags: mouse, touchpad, dconf

I'm currently running Ubuntu 14.04, and I'm trying to make changes to my Logitech K400r keyboard/trackpad combo (specifically, I want to increase the speed of the pointer, enable edge-scrolling, and disable tap-to-click). I have tried making these changes with dconf-editor, unfortunately, the options I choose for changes, while they show as being changed within the dconf-editor program, don't actually change for the system. Is there something I'm doing wrong? Is there a better tool for making these changes?

Answer (score 2):

Are you making sure to run dconf-editor as the user you wish to apply these changes to?

As in -- if you want to run these changes during your normal, every-day use of Ubuntu, just run dconf-editor as that user (so without running it as sudo).

Comment: I simply search for dconf editor and run it from there. I don't run it with sudo from terminal. Maybe I should give that a shot?

Edit: just tried running sudo dconf editor, same issue.

Comment: Thing is, the settings that dconf-editor manipulates are on a per-user basis, at least to a large extent. For example, I use dconf-editor to make sure the PC actually switches off (shutdown) when I press the power button. Normally, Ubuntu would show an interactive menu. However, I had to make sure NOT to run dconf-editor as sudo to accomplish this. Since the user I am running the Desktop Environment from obviously is not root.