# How can I make dconf-editor changes persistent for reboot?

Tags: 16.04, gnome

I'm using Ubuntu 16 LTS and I've installed dconf-editor to change the cursor size from 24 to 32. When I change the setting it is applied immediately and I can see the difference in size. However, when I reboot the size has reset to 24 (ie the default). I have tried multiple times now.

How can I make dconf-editor changes persistent for reboot?

This question was [asked](https://askubuntu.com/questions/542358/i-can-change-the-setting-options-in-dconf-editor-but-the-changes-i-make-dont-t) on this site over 3 years ago by someone else, but it was not answered. I did `mv ~/.config/dconf/ ~/.config/dconf.bak` to rule out corruption.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[This post](https://askubuntu.com/q/770915/32664) sounds similar to your issue (and with an apparent resolution).

In short, editing `com/canonical/unity/interface/cursor-scale-factor` in dconf-editor appears to persist cursor size.

Comment: Thanks, that worked. I guess there are some settings that are just not persistent.

Comment: This doesn't work in Bionic 18.04 LTS because that path is no longer available. Instead, there's a similar setting in accessibility: `Settings > Universal access > Cursor size > Medium`